# Dimple js modify scatter shape

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

Is there an easy way to modify the shape of the circles in a scatter plot using dimple.js?

I want different shapes for each color in this [scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlBGv.png). For instance, rectangles for blue, triangles for red, brackets for yellow...

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Since dimple.js is powered by d3.js, you should be able to modified. Here is scatter plat with triangle shape. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3244058

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by writing a custom plot function.

If you don't care about certain features (e.g. tooltips, animation, repeated draws etc), you can cut them out and it reduces the code to something very minimal. Here's the most basic plotter for drawing a star.

```
var myCustomPlotter = {
  stacked: false,
  grouped: false,
  supportedAxes: ["x", "y"],
  draw: function (chart, series, duration) {
    chart._group
      .selectAll(".my-series")
      .data(series._positionData)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
    // Path Generated at http://www.smiffysplace.com/stars.html
      .attr("d", "M 0 10 L 11.756 16.180 L 9.511 3.090 L 19.021 -6.180 L 5.878 -8.090 L 0 -20 L -5.878 -8.090 L -19.021 -6.180 L -9.511 3.090 L -11.756 16.180 L 0 10")
      .attr("transform", function (d) { 
      return "translate(" +
        dimple._helpers.cx(d, chart, series) + "," + 
        dimple._helpers.cy(d, chart, series) + ")"; 
    }) 
      .style("fill", "yellow")
      .style("stroke", "orange");
  }
};
```

http://jsbin.com/mafegu/6/edit?js,output

Once you start adding tooltips etc it will get more complicated but you can use the original bubble method  as a base and work from there:

https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/blob/master/src/objects/plot/bubble.js

Comment: John, can you please give me some suggestion, how I can overcome this issue with dimple.js  Thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879595/adding-selection-menu-using-d3-js